# alternative to PoolingOptions, any suggestions?

Tags: cassandra

Migrating from cassandra-driver-core(3.4.0) to java-driver-core (4.14.1) don't find an alternative to PoolingOptions class in new version, does anybody has implemented the same earlier or any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java driver is now driven by the [configuration file](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/4.x/manual/core/configuration) - you can override default configurations with your own stuff either with additional config file, or programmatically (see manual).  For pools there is a separate section called `pool` under `datastax-java-driver.advanced.connection` ([source](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/4.x/core/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L436)) where you can customize size of the pool, number of inflight requests, etc.